# Unique together constraint for two FK to same model, without order

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

How could I do a `unique_together` for a model:

```
class Team(models.Model:
    user_a = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='a')
    user_b = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='b')
```

And I want to make sure `user_a` and `user_b` can't be a duplicate, doesn't matter which order they are.
So `user_a=1`, `user_b=2` would constraint `user_a=2`, `user_b=1` also, instead of exact duplicate.

Is there a way to do this, without custom logic to check for saving the Team? I'm currently just letting them duplicate, then removing the duplicate fields with a RawSQL query.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want it like this way? Why not to specify `team` field for user?

Comment: Yes, this is just a simplified example, and they could be member of many teams, they just can't be member of the same "team" in different order.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked and you can use the `unique_together` attribute of `Meta` class in your model with Foreign Keys. Try something like:

```
class Team(models.Model:
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user_a", "user_b"))
    user_a = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='a')
    user_b = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='b')
```

If it doesn't suite your need, you could override the `save` or the `validate_unique` method of the model. See related doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique). But you would need to add your custom logic.